# How to order numeric dictionary keys with 2 digits

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python like the one below, containing about 20 keys:

```
a = { "1": "","2":"","3":""........"20":"" }
```

To sort the dictionary I'm doing the following:

```
 for key in sorted(a.iterkeys()):
        print key
```

However it doesn't seem to keep the keys in order. It will result in this output:

1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 3 4 5 6 7 .....

I was looking for something like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 ....

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Your code, as written, does not do what you say. In fact, it does exactly what you want. Most likely, the keys are actually `"1"`, `"2"`, etc., rather than `1`, `2`, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming your *real* dictionary looks like this:

```
a = {"1": "", "2": "", …, "20": ""}
```

Otherwise, you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place.

If that's the problem, the answer is this:

```
for key in sorted(a.iterkeys(), key=int):
    print key
```

The trick here is that `key` argument. You can pass any function you want as a `key` to `sorted` (and most other sorting-related functions), and it will call that function on all of the values and sort based on the result of that function, instead of on the actual values.

The builtin [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function takes any argument and (if possible) converts it to an integer. In particular, if you give it the string `"3"` it'll give you the number `3`, and if you give it `"20"`, it'll give you `20`. And, while `"3" > "20"` (because strings are compared alphabetically), `3 < 20` (because numbers are compared numerically).

See the [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html) in the docs for further details.

Comment: Thanks abarnert. That was quick :)

Comment: You are right, keys are being stored as strings. Thanks again for your explanation. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind third-party libraries, the [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) library is designed for cases exactly like this one (see @abarnert's answer for why this is needed):

```
from natsort import natsorted
for key in natsorted(a.iterkeys()):
    print key
```

Comment: While it's not necessary here, `natsort` is very cool for other cases, when you're sorting, say, `["Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Thing 11"]` and the appropriate key is much less obvious.

Comment: @abarnert True, but it provides a "it just works" solution to sorting strings of numbers for those who don't want to have to think about using a key. :)

Comment: Yeah, and, as I said, something the appropriate key is much less obvious, so it's definitely worth having this in your toolkit (which is why I upvoted the answer) even if you don't use it here.